# Is it possible to install Docker container in Windows -32 bit systems?

Tags: docker, 32-bit

I am getting error as Docker needs 64bit configuration, is there any way where i can install docker in 32 bit systems. It's a 32 bit i3 processor having windows 7 machine.

Comment: its better to specify machine and other details

Comment: Check this out, https://medium.com/@chrispatten/installing-and-running-docker-on-32-bit-windows-d18b95ee1fc3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the document of docker, it says that you can install it only on 64 bit machine.
But there is another solution if you don't have a 64 bit machine. Just use the below url to play with docker (it's official site) it works like a charm

[Docker play](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/)

Edit 1: Please note that this is only for **practise purpose**, Once your session is over your work will be lost.

Edit 2: I have found a very interesting site to practise docker [kodekloud](https://www.kodekloud.com/p/docker-labs)

Comment: Is the ip accessible outside labs-play?, I am trying to connect docker ip from above link you have added but it seems it is not accessible

Answer (score 3):

The first step to getting this whole setup to work is installing Oracle’s VirtualBox on the host system. Once the installation is complete, installing docker-machine is as simple as running the following in an Administrative PowerShell session:

```
choco install docker-machine -y
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
docker-machine env | Invoke-Expression
```

For more details You can follow [this](https://medium.com/@chrispatten/installing-and-running-docker-on-32-bit-windows-d18b95ee1fc3) blog.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not possible for current versions of the docker.

This was possible for early versions of docher (boot2docker 32bit iso), but the project is closed and thoroughly killed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).